# SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7 along with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition on my Win 7 notebook. Using since an Express edition this doesn't have SQL Server profiler enabled. Thus it's hard for me to debug my SQL Server 2005 applications.

I have a license for SQL Server 2005 (32 bit) and when I tried to install the client tools it gave a "known compatibility" error message. Is it possible to install SQL Server 2005 client tools (for 32 bit) only in the same machine?

Below is list of software on my machine

- Windows 7
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition
- Visual Studio 2010

Can any one advise.

thanks a zillion

Comment: So what was MS's solution to whatever known compatibility issue it was?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can use the SQL Server 2005 client tools for SQL Server 2008 R2. But if your main issue is the inability to use profiler, I suggest just running server-side traces instead. You don't get the fancy GUI, but you can still see all the same data.

Running a trace without profiler: [SQL Server Performance Statistics Using a Server Side Trace](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1035/sql-server-performance-statistics-using-a-server-side-trace/)

Note, one thing you won't be able to do with server-side tracing is to replay a trace.